# Create multiple background button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a button that have a double background, one that contains an icon (with fixed width) and the rest is normal text.

What I got for now is:

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

span {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="button">
  <span>x</span> Test
</div>


<div class="button">
  <span><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></span> Test
</div>
```

The problem of that method is that a 1px border is shown at the bottom and seems not very stable as method. How can I achieve this effect cleanly? Thanks

Comment: you can use bootstrap

Comment: do yu wan to use a gradient ?

Comment: Hey Keaire, if any of the answers helped you out you are welcome to accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. If none of the answers provided meaningful help consider rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of the span to 100%

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

span {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height:100%;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="button">
  <span>x</span> Test
</div>


<div class="button">
  <span><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></span> Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: grid` to place the items and have them vertically and horizontally centered and a `linear-gradient` to control the colors. It is automatically responsive and will work with all values you apply for `height` or `width` of `.button`.

```css
.button {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, lightblue 50%, lightcoral 50%);
  
  /* styling */
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="button">
  <span>x</span> 
  Test
</div>

<br>

<div class="button">
  <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
  Test
</div>
```

In case you want the icon-part or the label-part to be a certain size just change `grid-template-columns` to something like `grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;` and the `linear-gradient` respectively (`background: linear-gradient(to right, lightblue 25%, lightcoral 75%)`).